# Is it possible to highlight the first 5 rows in a SharePoint view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a view that sorts items based on a date field, from earliest to latest.

The order will change over time, as users make edits to the item dates.

I would like to apply formatting that will always highlight the first 5 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using modern layout you could use view formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(@rowIndex < 5 ,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning','')"
}
```

Details available here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/declarative-customization/view-formatting.md

Comment: SUCCESSFUL! Thanks @user1704029